# Implement "Add to favourites" from icon in cardview android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, sharedpreferences

In my App, **Add to favourites** icon inside my cardview. On clicking the icon, my card should be added to **my favorites list** and the icon should toggle to a different colour.

On clicking again it should be removed from my **favourites**. I want to accomplish this task through sharedpreference.

How i should proceed sequentially to accomplish this task?

Comment: you just place a image in your cardview where you want and write code on that image click as per you want. This may help you https://androidtutorialmagic.wordpress.com/android-material-design-tutorial/android-card-view-tutorial-imageview-textview-button/

Comment: i want to know the entire process, how to declare classes for shared preference, model, adapter and how to toggle images.

Comment: Do you check that link ?

Comment: SO is not a coding service. You need to code on your own. If you face any problems, come here with that specific problem and we will be happy to help you.

Comment: Yes i did check that link. As such i am having no problem with the layout. I just want to know how to implement that functionality.

Comment: Sorry . Actually i am very new to android. Infact this was my first app. While coding things got cluttered in my mind. I just wanted a fresh way of thinking for the task. @PrerakSola

Comment: We always **HELP**. But what you were asking was **Spoon Feeding**. We don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Hope you have all layouts done. If not - create them. Make sure Favourites is a ToggleButton
2. Create Adapter for your ListView or RecyclerView
3. Inside Adapter, when you are binding views, call:

   ```
       findViewById(R.id.btn_favourite).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void OnClick(View view) {
           if(view.isSelected) {
                markAsFavourite(item);
           } else {
                removeFromFavourites(item);
           }
       }
       });
   ```

   Where `item` is Object representing data for your List
4. Implement `markAsFavourite(item)`; and `removeFromFavourites(item);` methods. Here is a rough example of `markAsFavourite(item)` using SharedPreferences.

   ```
       Set itemIds = mSharedPreferences.edit().getStringSet(KEY, new Set());
       itemIds.put(item.getId);
       mSharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet(itemIds).commit();
   ```
5. Update data in Favourites ListView.

5.1 Get item ids from SharedPreferences

5.2 Select Item's sub-list according to ids.

5.3 Update Adapter for FavouritesList.